# Can jQuery tooltip be configured to keep the content on the DOM when it's not active?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jQuery tooltip with code like so:

```
$(document).tooltip({
  items: "#tooltip-origin",
  content: "<b id='tooltip-content'>tooltip</b>",
  open: function(e, ui){
     $(ui.tootip).appendTo $("#tooltip-origin")
  }
})
```

I've noticed that `$("#tooltip-content")` exists when the tooltip is active (the origin is being hovered over). But when I stop hovering the selector no longer finds anything. It seems the `content` is being removed from the DOM.

I'm not exactly bashing my head against the wall here. I could feasibly write my own tooltip system, or connect the tooltip content to a hidden node on the DOM for anything that needs to be persistent. But it would make my life easier to be able to configure jQuery's component instead.

At this point I'm looking at another tool to do this, [ptooltip](https://github.com/gi1242/jQuery.pTooltip) but I would prefer to have the official jQuery UI version if there is one.

Comment: Can be done. How long do you want to store it and where?

Comment: I want to store it permanently on the dom but have it toggle visibility on hover. Although to be honest ive moved on from this issue at this point, I ended up using the ptooltip plugin.